# Add items to gridview during runtime instead of replacing previous items

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, android-adapter

I've followed this tutorial to get a gridview that displays images using a custom adapter:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

I've adapted the code to show the images when an nfc card is presented to the phone, however if I present the card multiple times, the images in the gridview are just replaced. I wanted it so that when the phone reads the nfc card again, it adds the images to the gridview, instead of just replacing them.

How can I achieve this?

```
                //If the NFC card contains the word "pic"           
            if(thePayloadText.equals("pic")){

                gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

                gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));
        }

            //If the NFC card contains the word "test"
            if(thePayloadText.equals("test")){

                gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
                gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, PHOTOS));

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `setAdapter` will clear all the previous items. So you need to avoid `setAdapter` when you add new items.

Instead you need to add the new item into the existing adapter.

If your custom adapter is `ArrayAdapter`, You can simply add like this

```
imageAdapter.add(yourObject); // imageAdapter is the instance you created first time when you setAdapter.
```

`add()` method with call `notifyDataSetChanged` to notify the `GridView' to refresh the UI.

If your custom adapter is `BaseAdapter`, then have a add() method in the `Custom Adapter class` and call it to add new items.

```
public void add(String[] newImages){
    // add the items to the previous array
    this.mobileValues.addAll(Arrays.asList(newItems));
    // notify the data changed
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Hope it helps you.